# Eager load extended has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

Couldn't find anything about how to specify extended association with arguments in `includes`. Condsider:

```
Class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books do
    def of_genre(genre)
       where(genre: genre)
    end
  end
end
```

This can be used like: `Aurhor.first.books.of_genre('horror')`.
I want to use this with `includes`: `Author.where(...).includes(:books).where(books: ...)`
This will generate a left join, but due to the nature of my specific use case, I don't want it to join to books table, but rather an already filtered books table (hence the extension).
Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Are you sure that the join doesn't happen on a filtered books list?

Comment: Well that is my issue :), I don't know how to apply the `of_genre` extension here. By default this extension is not applied, but can be chained if used on an instance: `Aurhor.first.books.of_genre('horror')`. I was hoping this can be used somehow with eager load to specify the result table from which i want to load the association.

Comment: Does this work? Aurhor.first.books.of_genre('horror').includes(:books)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to create scopes on Book and then associations for them on Author, it will allow you to eager_load them but unfortunately create some overhead.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    scope :horror, -> { where(genre: "horror") } 
    scope :fantasy, -> { where(genre: "fantasy") }
 end

 class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :horror_books, -> { horror }
    has_many :fantasy_books, -> { fantasy }
 end

 Author.first.includes(:horror_books)
 Author.first.includes(:fantasy_books)
```

Comment: https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-to-preload-rails-scopes/

Comment: The parameter of the extension is not known ahead of time, that is why i cannot create scopes. In fact, in my use case its an id (of a third model) list.

Comment: Gotcha! Then indeed I'm not sure if it's possible. Can this approach help? http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/extending-has_many-association-proxy